# SAPUI5 Table getting recreated on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5, treetable

I have a sapui5 treetable getting updated one buttion click event. On button click i am getting data using ajax and want repopulate the existing tree table rendered on first call. I have simulated the issue in below bin. How to avoid recreating the table on button click?

I tried to check the otable was null before recreating the object but it did not help. Please advise.

http://jsbin.com/openui5-table-json/889/edit

Comment: Figured out the issue. Intialized table object ouside of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, you're recreating the table each time the press event occurs. As an alternate solution of yours, you can add a bit of logic to check if the table is already created.

```
if(sap.ui.getCore().byId('idTable')===undefined){
     //code to create table
}
```

http://jsbin.com/openui5-table-json/897/edit